# Автоматическое монтирование флэш-накопителей не срабатывает

Tags: kde, монтирование, linux

Система Alt-Linux 4.0. KDE тоже в целом старое. Но все работало, пока не намудрил с HAL, попытавшись обновить версию не с совсем с официального репозитория (Sisyphus) - там были некоторые мучения с версиями Alt-Linux В результате HAL половину свою обновил, а вторую подобрать не смог (что-то было с неподдерживаемыми зависимостями пакетов). Я восстановил старый HAL и при вставке флэшки KDE теперь пытается монтрировать ее.  Но проблема в том, что  тут же возникает сообщение об ошибке и невозможности подмонтрировать это устройство, из-за отсутствия прав... Разобраться пока мне так и не удалось. Может знает кто, что именно надо исправить (или смотреть для исправления).

Answer (score 1):

Аналогично намудрил сам в своё время на этой же версии. А ответов не нашёл ни на одном форуме ни у одного гуру. Лекарство одно - сносить. Тем более и версия древняя. Бэкапить данные и ставить новый. только не 5 - глючен он. KDesktop 6 вполне рабочая, только с некоторыми мониторами гемор. Но на замену всегда есть братья-близнецы Альта - PCLinuxOS и Rosa 2011 EE

Comment: Сносить как-то не хочется во время учебного процесса. Кроме того компы и Linux старые и боюсь, что более свежие версии просто не пойдут или будут тормозить еще хуже, чем сейчас. Да и хотелось бы саму причину понять, чтобы просто ручками исправить. На будущее.

Comment: Вот чесслово, "шашечки или ехать"? :) Если ехать, сносите, даже во время учебного процесса! Из Mandrake выросло три сына, дальше сказку сами знаете. С жар-птицей оказался только младший - PCLinuxOS.